# What is the default dark mode stylesheet used by PyQt

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6, darkmode

Since v5.12, PyQt has automatically switched to dark mode when that is the system default, at least on MacOS. The v5.12 stylesheet had a few missing features, but in v5.15 and v6, the default looks perfectly adequate. I would like to be able to switch dynamically between the default light and dark modes, but I cannot find documentation that identifies the appropriate stylesheet to use, *e.g.*, I can switch between three default stylesheets, but none of them are dark-themed.

```
>>> import PyQt5
>>> app = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
>>> PyQt5.QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.keys()
['macintosh', 'Windows', 'Fusion']
>>> app.setStyleSheet('Fusion')
```

The `setStyleSheet` function doesn't allow any keyword argument, so there doesn't seem to be an option such as `mode='dark'`. Does anyone know how to access the default styles used when the system itself switches from dark mode to light, or *vice versa*? None of the above options switch mode either way.

There are numerous questions about setting dark mode on StackOverflow, but all the recommendations involve installing another package, such as `qdarkstyle` or `qt-material`, or writing your own, whereas I just want to access the stylesheet that must already be installed.

Edit: I see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74308016/trying-to-make-a-dark-lightmode-switcher) that I should probably be asking about standard palettes rather than stylesheets. However, the question remains how to access the palettes used by PyQt when the system is in light or dark mode.

Comment: `app.setStyleSheet()` expects an **actual** style sheet syntax, `Fusion` is not a valid argument for that (including that of QWidget `setStyleSheet()`). Check the debug output and you'll probably see a "Could not parse application stylesheet" error. Also, the default behavior uses a *style* (QStyle), not a "style sheet"; in fact, when a style sheet is set, Qt parses it and uses a QStyleSheetStyle based on its parameters). That said, right now Qt doesn't provide an API to manually force dark or light mode, there are ways to achieve it through the macOS capabilities for an existing application.

Comment: Are you able to describe one of those ways?

Comment: Sorry, but no, as I don't use macOS (luckily ;-) ).

Comment: There is no defined palette or stylesheet as such - everything is determined internally by the macos style plugin, which determines the mode by calling out to the platform APIs. If you want all the gory details, take a look at the qt source code (e.g. *qmacstyle_mac.mm* and *qcore_mac.mm*) and search for `qt_mac_applicationIsInDarkMode`.

Comment: Thanks, @ekhumoro, that's very helpful. It would be nice if PyQt could expose the function calls that switch modes, although I can see that might not be possible. Perhaps I'll ask Phil Thompson on the PyQt mailing list.

Comment: @RayOsborn It's not a public API, so PyQt would never wrap it. You need to take this up with the Qt developers.

Comment: I think you found the answer you needed: access `QPalette`. There isn't really an underlying stylesheet that you can access. You can look into `qdarkstyle`'s qss file to get an idea of what the stylesheet *might* look like if it existed. Furthermore, if you're interested, PyQt6 has native Dark Mode handling with `Fusion`: https://www.qt.io/blog/dark-mode-on-windows-11-with-qt-6.5